# How to map array of objects to array of object properties with nested array MongoDB c#

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, nested, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to create the following methods to retrieve an array of ObjectId from a child array.

`GetStorageLocationIds()`

`GetStorageRoomIds(ObjectId locationId)`

`GetStorageSectionIds(ObjectId locationId, ObjectId roomId)`

`GetStorageShelfIds(ObjectId locationId, ObjectId roomId, ObjectId sectionId)`

`GetStorageSlotIds(ObjectId locationId, ObjectId roomId, ObjectId sectionId, ObjectId shelfId)` (this one may not be as difficult because it is already an array of ObjectId)

Each method should return an `IEnumerable<ObjectId>` containing an array of the `id` property of the appropriate array. I realize I could just get the entire document for every list but I would prefer a more efficient and elegant solution using the MongoDB c# driver.

This is an example document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5cb2271a4bd93c0dec4db163"),
...
"StorageRooms" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cb49adc36ad6719bf947103"),
        ...
        "StorageSections" : [ ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cb49afa36ad6719bf947106"),
        ...
        "StorageSections" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5cb49bb8c40cd319cb2511ae"),
                ...
                "StorageShelves" : [ ]
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5cb49bb8c40cd319cb2511af"),
                ...
                "StorageShelves" : [
                    {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5cb49bfe8d259019d9207f48"),
                        ...
                        "StorageSlotIds" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5cb49bfe8d259019d9207f49"),
                        ...
                        "StorageSlotIds" : [ ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cb49afa36ad6719bf947107"),
        ...
        "StorageSections" : [ ]
    }
]
```

}

The above methods should return the following array, using the above example document as the input data. (assuming it is the only one in the collection):

`GetStorageLocationIds()` ->  `["5cb2271a4bd93c0dec4db163"]`

`GetStorageRoomIds("5cb2271a4bd93c0dec4db163")` -> `["5cb49adc36ad6719bf947103,"5cb49afa36ad6719bf947106", "5cb49afa36ad6719bf947107"]`

`GetStorageSectionIds("5cb49afa36ad6719bf947106")` -> `["5cb49bb8c40cd319cb2511ae","5cb49bb8c40cd319cb2511af"]`

etc...

So far, I've been able to write the first one: `GetStorageLocationIds`. This is the code seems to work well:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ObjectId>> GetAllDocumentIdsAsync(string database, string collection,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return (await _mongoContext.MongoClient.GetDatabase(database).GetCollection<T>(collection)
            .Find(new BsonDocument())
            .Project(new BsonDocument {{"_id", 1}})
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken)).Select(x => x[0].AsObjectId);
    }
```

When it comes to the next one, I tried using `ProjectionDefinition` but all it did was return the document `id` instead of each `id` in the `StorageRooms` array.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ObjectId>> GetStorageRoomIdsAsync(ObjectId id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var filter = Builders<StorageLocation>.Filter.And(
            Builders<StorageLocation>.Filter.Where(location => location.Id == id));
        var projectionDefinition = Builders<StorageLocation>.Projection.Include(location => location.StorageRooms);

        var projectionResult = await ProjectAsync(filter, projectionDefinition, cancellationToken);
        return projectionResult.Select(x => x[0].AsObjectId);
    }
```

After some attempts at using aggregation, I believe it will work with `Unwind` but I'm lost at how to implement this in c# correctly. Thanks in advance for any help.

*Edit Note: ObjectId and string are used exchangeably in this question for brevity. I use AutoMapper for my actual project*

## Edit 2:

The answer from micki worked for `GetStorageRoomIds`. I'm now trying to use the following code for `GetStorageSectionIds` but get an error:

```
return from location in AsQueryable()
            where location.Id == id
            from room in location.StorageRooms
            where room.Id == roomId
            from section in room.StorageSections 
            select section.Id;
```

The error is [here](https://hastebin.com/goyaduyebe.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For queries like this you can run `AsQueryable()` on your `IMongoCollection` and then use LINQ syntax like below:

```
var storageRoomIds = from location in Col.AsQueryable()
                     where location.Id == locationId
                     from room in location.StorageRooms
                     select room.Id;
```

You can also turn on [MongoDB profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) to see that it will be translated into

```
"pipeline" : [
    {
        "$match" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cb2271a4bd93c0dec4db163")
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind" : "$StorageRooms"
    },
    {
        "$project" : {
            "_id" : "$StorageRooms._id"
        }
    }
],
```

So you have both simple C# code and efficient MongoDB query

EDIT: for level below you can still use LINQ syntax:

```
var rooms = from location in Col.AsQueryable()
            where location.Id == locationId
            from room in location.StorageRooms
            select new
            {
                roomId = room.Id,
                storageIds = room.StorageSections.Select(x => x.Id)
            };

var storageIds = from room in rooms
                where room.roomId == roomId
                from storageId in room.storageIds
                select storageId;


var result = storageIds.ToList();
```

and this gets translated into:

```
"pipeline" : [
    {
        "$match" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cb2271a4bd93c0dec4db163")
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind" : "$StorageRooms"
    },
    {
        "$project" : {
            "roomId" : "$StorageRooms._id",
            "storageIds" : "$StorageRooms.StorageSections._id",
            "_id" : 0
        }
    },
    {
        "$match" : {
            "roomId" : ObjectId("5cb49afa36ad6719bf947106")
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind" : "$storageIds"
    },
    {
        "$project" : {
            "storageIds" : "$storageIds",
            "_id" : 0
        }
    }
],
```

Comment: How do you recommend doing the nested ones? I tried adding another `where` and `from` clause but I get `$project or $group does not support {document}` as an error.

Comment: @A.S. could you create another question and show your attempts there ?

Comment: @micki I added an edit with my attempted code and error message

Comment: @A.S. modified my answer